# C# and multithreading logic

Tags: c#, multithreading, file

What i am trying to do is create a function that reads all the content of file and regex something. 
What i have done so far is created a function

read_content(string filename);

but before this function i ask user to choose a directory and then read all the names of file present in there

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
{
save in array
}
```

and i have started a thread

```
 var t = new Thread(() => read_content(filename));
  t.Start();
```

This is all working fine, now i want to make it multi thread, right now its single thread

i want a user to enter like start 10 thread and these threads read one file at a time ultil reaches to end

I tried searching on google but could not find like my need, i dont want whole code  just tell me logic or some basic code, want to learn and code on my own

**EDIT:** Seems like i have more vote for threadpool, soo a link to good tut would be appreciated

Comment: foreach through files and for each file add task to ThreadPool, not perfect but should work without many lines of code ;]

Comment: @wudzik thanks for reply, but i dont want to create 100 thread if there are 100 file in a folder, i just want 10 -15 threads working, reading one by one...

Comment: @aki003 you can set maxthreads in ThreadPool, or another solution to pass 1/10 of all filenames to one thread in threadpool :D

Comment: @wudzik any good tutorial for beginner ??

Comment: @aki003 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx  , it's kind of microsoft style tutorial (many code, less logic), but it explains threadpool enough to use it in this simple approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

You shouldn't set the amount in threads by hand - you should let the system take care of this. The TPL does this for you, so just create the tasks, and they will be executed eventually. Usually, one task per core is executed (not sure though).

Your code could be like:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()) {
    var filename = file.FullName;
    new Task(() => {
        read_content(filename);
    }).Start();
}
```

Note: your code doesn't check when the thread is finished, so I haven't included this either. If you want this, you have to keep the tasks in a list, and check if the tasks have finished.

Comment: +1. As a bonus, equivalent with PLINQ: `dir.GetFiles().AsParallel().ForAll(file => read_content(file.FullName));` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) class and call `File.ReadAlltext` on each file (:

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(<method>, <obj_arg>);
```

This will reuse the threads and won't create thread for every file.
You can perform Join at the end of the foreach.

```
thread.Join();
```

Have you considered using asynchronous feature of C# 5